# Check if a button click sets array length to 2 with React testing library

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs

I'm testing a React app for the first time and I'm struggling to write tests that check if an array in a component has 2 elements on first render and on clicking a button.

The error I'm getting is `TypeError: Expected container to be an Element, a Document or a DocumentFragment but got string.`

Here's the component where I need to test `usersCards` - it needs to have two elements on first render and every time the user clicks 'deal'.
I'm not sure how to deal with variables in components - do I mock it up in the test file? Ant help appreciated!

```
\\imports

export default function Home(){
    const startHandSize = 2
    
    const [starterDeck, setStarterDeck] = useState(shuffle(deckArray))
    const [howManyDealt, setHowManyDealt] = useState(startHandSize)
    const [total, setTotal] = useState(0)
    const [ace, setAce] = useState(0)

    const deal = () => {
        setHowManyDealt(startHandSize)
        setStarterDeck(shuffle(deckArray))
        setAce(0)
    }

    const hit = () => !bust && setHowManyDealt(prev => prev + 1)

    const usersCards = starterDeck.slice(-howManyDealt)

    const bust = total > 21;

    useEffect(() => {
        setTotal(usersCards.reduce((a, e) => a + e.value, 0) + ace)
    }, [ace, usersCards])

    return(
        <div>
        { 
          <>
          <button data-testid="deal" onClick={deal}>DEAL</button>

            <button data-testid="hit" disabled={bust} onClick={hit}>HIT</button>

            <button disabled={bust}>STAND</button>

            <Total total={total}/> 
     
        {usersCards.map(card => (
            <Card data-testid="test-card" key={card.index}
                card={card} setTotal={setTotal} total={total}
                ace={ace} setAce={setAce}
            />
        ))}
          </>}
        </div>
    )
}
```

Here's the test:

```
//Deal button test
test("on initial render, two cards are displayed", () => {
    render(<Home />)

    const cards = getAllByTestId('test-card')

    expect(cards.length).toEqual(2)
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess something like that would work:

```
test("on initial render, two cards are displayed", () => {
  const { getAllByTestId } = render(<Home />);
  const cards = getAllByTestId('test-card');
  expect(cards.length).toEqual(2);
});

test("two new cards should be displayed after clicking the button", () => {
  const { getAllByTestId, getByTestId } = render(<Home />);
  const dealButton = getByTestId('deal');
  fireEvent.click(dealButton);
  const cards = getAllByTestId('test-card');
  expect(cards.length).toEqual(2);
});
```

Comment: Yes, I see, I tried this but it still can't see the 'test-card' testid. Should I have it where it is now?

Comment: A sandbox would help

Comment: Sure, here it is: https://codesandbox.io/s/github/julianowic/blackjack

Comment: You have to move your ````data-testid="test-card"```` to Card.js like ````<div data-testid="test-card" className="card-group">````